# How to solve the Errors when reading .csv file into array with Python

Tags: python

I have a .csv file in which has such data:

```
8 15 -2.5 -2.5 -0.5 13531.13 97

8 15 -2.5 -2.5 1.5 13530.49 97

8 15 -2.5 -2.5 -0.5 13531.33 97

8 15 -2.5 -1.5 1.5 13530.7 97
```

........

I want to do some data processing on them with Python, so I wrote following codes, unfortunately met errors:

```
import numpy as np

csv_data = np.loadtxt('R(97)8-15.csv', usecols=1,skiprows=1,dtype='float')

print(csv_data)
```

the result of running is:

```
============== RESTART: D:\Ion_Trap\738nm_Stabilization\read.py ==============

[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1]
```

And I tried another way:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt

data = genfromtxt('R(97)8-15.csv', delimiter='    ', dtype="float")

print(data)
```

the result is :

```
============== RESTART: D:\Ion_Trap\738nm_Stabilization\read.py ==============

[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
```

Could someone help me figure out what's wrong, and I would be deep appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

`csv_data = np.loadtxt('file.csv', dtype='float')` works.

See here -> https://repl.it/@LukeStorry/63053770

Comment: thanks for reply, i tired your solution, however, when i run the "print(csv_data)", the result show :  
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '8,15,-2.5,-2.5,-0.5,-0.5,13531.12807,97'

Comment: Actually, I want to read each column into a separate array, and dont know how to do it exactly

Comment: Well then what is the actual format of your csv? Can you make a fork of that repl above with the actual csv format in it and send me a link?

Comment: https://repl.it/@liuyang59/QuickwittedPeruLocation#main.py, I dont understand it doesn't show any error in the link though it did on my pc with python 3.7.2

Comment: It might be a filesystem issue. Make sure both the files are in the same folder, and make sure none of the files or folders have any brackets or any characters that aren't lover case alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `delimiter` parameter is not necessary in your case in `np.genfromtxt`. Try without it

Comment: after remove delimiter,  it still shows "nan" on my pc with python 3.7.2